# Select Vendor ID based on another columns' value from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I am writing a query to get data based on the item that has a `VENDOR_ID` with a  minimum value in a column called `ITM_VNDR_PRIORITY`. The `ITM_VNDR_PRIORITY` comes from another table that shares the key `VENDOR_ID`.

Query I am using to get the vendor's associated with an item:

```
SELECT * 
FROM PS_ITM_VENDOR
WHERE INV_ITEM_ID = '1003'
```

**Results:**

```
 SETID  INV_ITEM_ID   VENDOR_SETID   VENDOR_ID  ITMV_PRIORITY_LOC  ITM_ID_VNDR   ITM_VNDR_PRIORITY
 SHARE  1003          SHARE          84764A     000001             CFG246        3      
 SHARE  1003          SHARE          CAMLAB     000001             CAT895        4
 SHARE  1003          SHARE          GYRENT     000001             TDOC-7FS      2
 SHARE  1003          SHARE          RLMED      000001             CAT895        1
```

I want to select the vendor for this Item ID that has the lowest `ITM_VNDR_PRIORITY` (1 in this example which is for VENDOR_ID "RLMED") and only return that vendor's rows to this query below where I am currently returning ALL vendor's associated to the item:

```
SELECT *
FROM PS_ITM_VNDR_UOM UPDEV
WHERE INV_ITEM_ID = '1003'
```

**Results:**

```
SETID   INV_ITEM_ID  VENDOR_SETID  VENDOR_ID   VNDR_LOC
--------------------------------------------------------
SHARE   1003         SHARE         GYRENT      000001
SHARE   1003         SHARE         RLMED       000001
SHARE   1003         SHARE         84764A      000001
SHARE   1003         SHARE         CAMLAB      000001
SHARE   1003         SHARE         GYRENT      000001
SHARE   1003         SHARE         RLMED       000001
```

I want this query to return only the item's associated with Vendor "RLMED" based on that vendor having the lowest (MIN) priority. This is what I have written so far as I'm not sure how to only get the vendor Id with the minimum ITM_VNDR_PRIORITY associated to the item.

```
SELECT *
FROM PS_ITM_VNDR_UOM UPDEV
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_ITM_VENDOR UPDEC ON UPDEV.SETID = UPDEC.SETID 
                                    AND UPDEV.INV_ITEM_ID = UPDEC.INV_ITEM_ID 
                                    AND UPDEV.VENDOR_SETID = UPDEC.VENDOR_SETID 
                                    AND UPDEV.VENDOR_ID = UPDEC.VENDOR_ID 
WHERE UPDEV.INV_ITEM_ID = '1003'
```

In this example the desired results would be the following (Returning vendor "RLMED" that has the lowest (MIN) priority):

```
SETID   INV_ITEM_ID  VENDOR_SETID  VENDOR_ID   VNDR_LOC
--------------------------------------------------------
SHARE   1003         SHARE         RLMED       000001
SHARE   1003         SHARE         RLMED       000001
```

**EDIT:**

I tried using this query but it still returns all vendors, and not the lowest priority vendor

```
SELECT *
FROM PS_ITM_VNDR_UOM UPDEV
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_ITM_VENDOR UPDEC ON UPDEV.SETID = UPDEC.SETID 
AND UPDEV.INV_ITEM_ID = UPDEC.INV_ITEM_ID AND UPDEV.VENDOR_SETID = UPDEC.VENDOR_SETID AND UPDEV.VENDOR_ID = UPDEC.VENDOR_ID 
WHERE UPDEV.INV_ITEM_ID = '1003'
 AND EXISTS (SELECT MIN(ITM_VNDR_PRIORITY)
             FROM PS_ITM_VENDOR UPDEC
             WHERE UPDEC.INV_ITEM_ID = UPDEV.INV_ITEM_ID
             AND UPDEC.VENDOR_ID = UPDEC.VENDOR_ID)
```

Comment: Any other suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT UPDEV.*
FROM PS_ITM_VNDR_UOM UPDEV LEFT OUTER JOIN
     PS_ITM_VENDOR UPDEC
     ON UPDEV.SETID = UPDEC.SETID AND
        UPDEV.INV_ITEM_ID = UPDEC.INV_ITEM_ID AND 
        UPDEV.VENDOR_SETID = UPDEC.VENDOR_SETID AND
        UPDEV.VENDOR_ID = UPDEC.VENDOR_ID 
WHERE UPDEV.INV_ITEM_ID = 1003 AND
      UPDEC.ITM_VNDR_PRIORITY = (SELECT MIN(UPDEC2.ITM_VNDR_PRIORITY)
                                 FROM PS_ITM_VENDOR UPDEC2
                                 WHERE UPDEC2.SETID = UPDEC.SETID AND
                                      UPDEC2.INV_ITEM_ID = UPDEC.INV_ITEM_ID AND 
                                       UPDEC2.VENDOR_SETID = UPDEC.VENDOR_SETID AND
                                       UPDEC2.VENDOR_ID = UPDEC.VENDOR_ID 
                                );
```

In particular, with an index on `PS_ITM_VNDR_UOM(INV_ITEM_ID, ITM_VNDR_PRIORITY)`, this should be very fast.

Comment: The table `PS_ITM_VNDR_UOM UPDEV` does not have the column `ITM_VNDR_PRIORITY` so this doesn't work. Only `PS_ITM_VENDOR` contains the field `ITM_VNDR_PRIORITY`

Comment: I edited the post above, however what I tried in the Edit still does not work as expected.